# Quasiconformal constant in Nielsen isomorphism theorem

Tags: teichmuller-theory, quasiconformal

Let $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ be two faithfull and discrete representations of the fundamental group of a compact surface into $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$. The Nielsen isomorphism theorem says that there exists a $(\rho_1,\rho_2)$ equivariant $K$-quasiconformal homeomorphism $\psi$ of the hyperbolic plane.

> Question1: how to relate $K$ and $\rho_1,\rho_2$ ?

Actually I would like to say that if a sequence of representations $(\rho_n)_n$ converges to $\rho$ (for the compact open topology), then the associated sequence of $K_n$-qc maps
$(\psi_n)_n$ converges to the identity map uniformly on compact sets (the pointwise convergence is straighforward). From standard properties of qc maps, it suffices to know that the $K_n$ are bounded from above, so question 1 would help.

> Question 2: Is there a reference stating explicitely the uniform convergence on compact sets of $(\psi_n)_n$?

thanks!

Comment: This is well-studied since 1960s; google "quasiconformal stability".